# In python the input() function does not work for me under this specific circumstance

Tags: python, file, input, text

While trying to make a simple text file reader / editor I found out that I get an error every time I use the input function when trying to immediately give value to a variable

File ".\textFileHandler.py", line 3, in 
    input2 = input("What is the name of the text file?")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
input=input("1 - Open an existing file\n2 - Create a new file\n3 - Add elements to an existing file")
if input=="1":
    input2 = input("What is the name of the text file?")
    file=open(input2+".txt","r")
    textContent=file.readlines()
    print(textContent)
    file.close()
elif input=="2":
    input2 = input("How would you like to name your new file? ")
    file = open(input2+".txt","w")
    string = input("Input text: ")
    file.write(string)
    file.close()
elif input=="3":
    input2 = input("What is the name of the text file? ")
    file = open(input2+".txt","a")
    string = input("Input text: ")
    file.write(string)
    file.close()

input("Press any key to exit.")
```

Comment: You called the *function* `input()`, and assigned its result to the *variable* `input`.  The function is no longer available to you, since you overwrote its name.

Comment: `input=input` this looks immediately suspect. don't use built-in names like `input` or `str` or `list` etc. for your variable names.

Comment: after changing the variable name from input to in, i get this error:   File ".\textFileHandler2.py", line 1
    in=input("1 - Open an existing file\n2 - Create a new file\n3 - Add elements to an existing file")
     ^

Comment: "in" is also a key word. Use "result"

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input=input("1 - Open an existing file\n2 - Create a new file\n3 - Add elements to an existing file")
```

Shadowing builtins in Python is an unfortunate gotcha.  One effective method for eliminating this problem is using an editor that highlights builtins differently from other names.